# Calling a secured API using Swift and Client Credentials

Tags: swift, api, networking

My goal is to call an API, protected by OAuth 2.0 with grant type Client Credentials. I'm not necessarily interested in a code example, just best practice from someone with good knowledge of Swift architecture. Although an example would be great!

**What I'm trying to implement in summary is the following:**

1. When a button is pressed, it calls function "getStock()"
2. The getStock() function calls a getToken() function in another class to request a bearer token
3. A network call is made and a token is returned in the http call. Once the network call is compelete, the token is passed back to the getStock() function to make the API call by including the bearer token in the header.

I've created an OAuthGenerator class which I can call and it successfully returns a token.

My problem is I don't know how to return the access token to another class, and the nature of a network call means I need to wait for the returned value before making the call to my actual API.

If you suggest using a Swift Networking library instead, I'd be interested in looking at that. I've looked at a few, but cannot find an example implementation using Client Credentials.

```
    func getStock() {

        OAuthTokenGenerator().getToken()

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://myapi.com/stock)!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)

        request.addValue("Bearer " + accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

                 request.httpMethod = "GET"

                 URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, err) in
                 guard let data = data else { return }
                 do {
                 let stock = try
                    JSONDecoder().decode(Stock.self, from: data) // decode JSON object based on above Constructor
                         DispatchQueue.main.async { // Async make call when ready

                            self.StockLabel.text = stock.stockTotal
                            self.current_fy.text = stock.currentFYTotal
                            self.previous_fy.text = stock.previousFYTotal

                         }
                     } catch let jsonErr {
                         print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
                     }
                 }.resume()

     }

    @IBAction func buttonSubmit(_ sender: UIButton) {
        getStock()
    }
```

```
import Foundation

class OAuthTokenGenerator {

    func getToken() {

        let headers = ["content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]

            let postData = NSMutableData(data: "grant_type=client_credentials".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            postData.append("&client_id=*****************".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
            postData.append("&client_secret=*****************".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

            let apiURL = "https://example-api-token-generator.com/identity/v1/token"

            guard let url = URL(string: apiURL) else { return }
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)

            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
            request.httpBody = postData as Data

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            do {
            let token = try
            JSONDecoder().decode(Token.self, from: data) // decode JSON object based on above Constructor
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { // Async make call when ready

                        print(token.access_token)

                    }

                } catch let jsonErr {
                    print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
                }

            }.resume()
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing, I suppose you should save the token with core data framework before first app launch, so that you can recall it whenever you want and fear it always present in the app because core data value is a persistent value and always remains present even when you kill the app. After saving it, every time you log in you can recall it in an if where you declare that if the token received is the same as the one saved in the core data then it enters, otherwise present an alert that explain the error ...